# Akamai url is not hitting dispatcher in AEM

Tags: apache, aem, vhosts, akamai

I have configured everything in Apache and dispatcher modules in AEM to use Akamai URL.

Farms and renders and *vhost*. When I try to access the domain, I receive an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

There is no entry in the Apache logs. It appears that the Akamai URL is not even being served by Apache.

Do you have any idea how to debug this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue to me, neither Apache-, nor programming-related ([help/on-topic]). You might find better help on other stackexchange sites, where this question is on-topic.